# Apple Watch Static Notification View Insets

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

I noticed a difference between a push notification from an iPhone-only application and an Apple Watch compatible app, and I wish to make my Watch-compatible app display a notification similarly to a normal iPhone-only app push notification.

Watch-compatible app:

[image: Lack of insets!]

iPhone-only app:

[image: Proper insets]

In my Watch app, the notification view (this is a screenshot from an actual Apple Watch) has weird insets (spacing between the actual text and the box), whereas the iPhone-only app has properly spaced insets. I tried setting the width of the Label of the notification text to a size smaller than the border and it worked (sort of, as seen above), but I was unable to set the top and bottom insets (the spacing between the top and bottom boundaries of the box and the text) with any of the options available to me in interface builder.

How should I go about setting the top insets for the Apple Watch to ensure a coherent look with the rest of WatchOS?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add a group to your static notification and drag the label inside it.

[image]